# Win10 display computer's password

Tags: windows-10, passwords

I have a computer, running on Windows 10 who is already login and I want to display the computer's password without reseting the password.

Comment: This isn't how password security works.  To change/reset the password you need the current password.  Otherwise, anyone with access to your machine has access to your account details.  Even an admin account can only reset (not view) a password.

Comment: Is there a way I can remove the password?

Comment: have a look here:  http://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/